# sharepoint-2013-search-consuming-much-disk-space-on-c-drive

Tags: sharepoint-server

After reset search index and ran full crawl 
my c drive full and consumed more space and again index component went down showing yellow mark

Now c drive full not able to access CA

Now what steps need to follow clear space and move index another location 
Because I have content more than 200gb

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should move your index to another drive. It is not a good practice to keep the search index in your C drive. It may also cause performance issues during the crawl.

Here is the instructions on how to do it:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/search/manage-the-index-component

Here is another useful link: 
http://blog.sharepointgeek.nl/post/2013/09/18/Move-the-search-index-location-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx

Here is a nice function created by Ivan j.:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Move-SharePoint-2013-242869e2

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. I will move to another drive but how to clear space in c drive ?central admin not working I think because of no space in c drive .if i will do index rest it will clear space them I will move index or delete manually ?

Comment: Or another option delete search service and Create  new search service with custom index location with  powershell

Comment: You do not need the central administration to move the index. All you need is to run some PowerShell commands. You can also delete the index folder in C drive.
here is an article explains how to find your index location:  https://itgroove.net/mmman/2015/04/30/how-to-determine-your-sharepoint-2013-search-index-location-and-default-search-index-location/

Comment: if you delete the search service application, all your managed properties and other customization will be gone. I would suggest you to delete the folder in C drive and move the index to another drive and re-index...